# How does one construct an octagon and side pairing transformations on that octagon, so that the surface is a closed surface of genus 2?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I am aiming to determine what are the initial characteristics of a side-pairing transformations for a hyperbolic octagon so that a Fuchsian group may be generated and a surface of genus 2 can be formed from the quotient of the hyperbolic plane and a Fuchsian group.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What I just know is that the side-pairing transformations generate a Fuchsian group. I am looking for a reference that characterizes an octagon with side-pairing transformations...,i.e, are there necessary (and sufficient conditions) that qualify an octagon and a set of side-pairing transformations that SHOULD GO HAND-IN-HAND in order to generate a Fuchsian group.

Comment: Aren't there a small number of candidate pairings?  Just start trying some by hand.